# Convert Javascript Date Object to JSON date

Tags: javascript, json, date

I'm trying to convert a timestamp made by

`var now = new Date().getTime();`

which creates the timestamp 1349916512100.

I want the date to be formatted like

`\/Date(1349916512100)\/`

to be used in a JSON string, right now I'm just concatonating the `\/Date` and `\/`, (like the example above) but is there a better/proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: not really. There are other ways, but what you're doing is probably the simplest way.

There's an interesting article on the subject [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_serialize_dates_to_json.ashx), but what's being described is more academic than practical.